# StripeAPI checkout blocked by IONOS, locally works fine

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments, ionos

I just hosted my ASP.NET Core MVC website on IONOS, and when I try to checkout on the cart and waiting for the stripe page to load, I have this message after 1 min of charging :

The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable.
Please try again later.
9eeb7ddf3b19029e2f372010a516dd7d d53615e798fecc1eb02f23aa4cd8f9c7 917ff949b7dc5126f56ec485b2a3c885

The checkout works fine locally.

I tried with a simplified exemple of checkout, but the same error.
I think it's the ionos firewall who are blocking stripe API. But i don't have access to this settings, to try to give permission to stripe API.
Maybe it's something else, if someone can help figure this out.
Thanks

Comment: would you mind sharing a link?

Comment: Yess This is where I hosted just the shopping section, in the nav bar click shopping and checkout
www.freekscode.fr

Comment: I can't find Shopping and Checkout. sorry